# offline mapping with slam_toolbox does not publish /map

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, ros2, mapping

I am trying to obtain an offline map by using slam_toolbox with the F1TENTH car. Setup on the car is ros foxy and ubuntu 20.04

First, I collected rosbag of all topics by ros2 bag record -a

Then runned the offline_launch.py of slam_toolbox and played the recorded bag file. On rviz, I can see the movement of base_link, however there is a warning on map display saying No map received.

When I echo /map topic, it does not show anything so I guess slam_toolbox does not publish any data to it.

Am I missing a step or doing something wrong while trying to create an offline map? Any help would be much appreciated since I cannot find any documentation regarding the offline mapping of slam_toolbox and there seems to be not much information on google regarding this topic.

Comment: Please update the question wit hthe actual warnings in the terminal. Are you sure you captured your TF tree? Are you replaying your rosbag with the clock and have sim time set in the slam toolbox node?